# PortalSiteMapProvider.GlobalNavSiteMapProvider get parent nodes when "display the same navigation items as the parent site" is set

Tags: navigation, custom, portalsitemapprovider

We are trying to build a Custom Navigation Web Control to handle our Global Navigation.

The below code works fine until the subsites have "*Display the same navigation items as the parent site*" set. Then the result is blank.

```
PortalSiteMapProvider oMap = PortalSiteMapProvider.GlobalNavSiteMapProvider;

foreach (SiteMapNode node in oMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes)
{
    // add the children of the root site
    htmlOutput += renderTopLevelLink(node, isfirst, currUrl);
    isfirst = false;
}
```

When "*Display the same...*" is set, how can I retrieve the parent navigation node?

I've tried using the `FindSiteMapNode(oWeb.Url)` but the result is my Root Navigation.

P.S. I get the oWeb.Url this way:

```
protected SPWeb GetNavigationWeb(SPWeb oWeb)
{
    if (oWeb.Navigation.UseShared == true)
    {
        oWeb = GetNavigationWeb(oWeb.ParentWeb);
    }
    return oWeb;
}
```